# Nested dict and retrieving key/values

Tags: python

If I have the following nested dict:

```
dicta = {'Saturday, August 26': {"Hawai'i": 'Massachusetts', 'Portland State': 'BYU', 'Oregon State': 'Colorado State', 'South Florida': 'San José State', 'Stanford': 'Rice'}}
```

If I wanted to access the games (which are themselves values of the outer key), is the only way to get to them is with a throwaway variable like:

```
for day in dicta:
    game_day = day  
        for home, away in day_dict[game_day].items():
            print(home, away)
```

I don't really care about the variable `game_day` as I already know the dict in question has the games in it I need.  But I do need to access those games.  So do I have to go about creating a variable just to get key:value pairs I need?  Just trying to figure out a better way if there is one.

Edit: Update dict variable to same name as name in for loop

Comment: Why are you assigning the `day` to `game_day`? You can just use `day`.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the day before you iterate over the items in the dictionary, why not just do:

```
day = 'Saturday, August 26'
for home, away in day_dict[day].items():
    print home, away
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your sample dictionary has a different name than the ones you used in the loop, it is not very clear to me what you're trying to do, but seems like you are looking for a more efficient way to traverse your dictionary and finding the values you want.

For that matter I recommend checking out the [Python documentation on dictionaries](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm), it is pretty helpful and introduces a lot of useful functions.

So one thing that might help you is the keys() and values() attributes of an= dictionary object. You can get a list of all the dictionary's keys by making a loop like:

```
for key in dict.keys():
    # do things with key
```

Or you can do things with the values of your dictionary like this:

```
for value in dict.values():
    # do things with value
```

Hope that's helpful!

Comment: There is almost never any need for the `keys` method; a `dict` iterator already iterates over the keys of a `dict`.

Comment: Yes, but if you need to use the keys of a dictionary as a list, you can do so by using this attr.

Comment: You can always just write `list(d)` to get a list of the keys. You *certainly* don't need it for a `for` loop, which unnecessarily creates a full list of the keys in memory rather than just getting them from the dict as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to access just the games without specifying the day, you can try this:

```
for a, b in dicta.items():
      for c, d in b.items():
          print "opponent 1: ", c
          print "opponent 2: ", d
```